# Numbered filenames in C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, cout

I have data that I would like to output to files named matrix_1.txt, matrix_2.txt, etc.

The following code works in visual studio:

```
//get ready to write to file
std::ofstream myfile;

//define filename
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "output_matrix_" << sim_index << ".txt";
myfile.std::ofstream::open (oss.str());

//write to file
myfile<<"stuff\n";

//close the file
myfile.close();
```

But when I run this using g++, I get the following error message:

```
laplace_calc.cpp:240: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char, std::ch                ar_traits<char> >::open(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/fstream:696: note: candidat                es are: void std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [w                ith _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
```

Can someone provide a solution that works with g++? Thanks!

Comment: Compile with C++11 enabled or use `oss.str().c_str()`.  Either one.

Comment: @Drew The OP is using GCC 4.4.6. Either they need to use C++0x or its support is incomplete.

Comment: Why do you write `myfile.std::ofstream::open` instead of `myfile.open`?

Comment: On the g++ compiler, I noticed I had to specify std::cout instead of cout, so I specified the libraries being used.I believe that the two statements are equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable C++11 support for GCC using the `-std=c++0x` switch.

Alternatively, use `oss.str().c_str()` to obtain a pointer to the null-terminated string, and pass that to `open()`, since that overload is supported prior to C++11.

If you look at [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open), you'll see that the overload to `open()` that takes a `std::string` is only implemented in C++11.

Also, as mentioned in a comment, you only need `myfile.open(oss.str())`, or simply declare `myfile` and open the file at the same time:

```
std::ofstream myfile(oss.str());
```